# Moving scatter plot circles with context zooming and brush in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create a Focus+Context+Tooltip graph based on d3 example of http://bl.ocks.org/1667367. I have got the basic charts working but when I try to zoom into an area using focus chart, my 'circles' which I plan to use for tooltip do not move.

This is my code:

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var data = [{
'Wed Jan 23 00:00:00 IST 2013': 3383387
}, {
'Thu Jan 24 00:00:00 IST 2013': 3883387
}, {
'Fri Jan 25 00:00:00 IST 2013': 4383387
}, {
'Sat Jan 26 00:00:00 IST 2013': 2383387
}, {
'Sun Jan 27 00:00:00 IST 2013': 5383387
}, {
'Mon Jan 28 00:00:00 IST 2013': 2283387
}];

var format = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S IST %Y");

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
.x(x2)
.on("brush", brush);

var area = d3.svg.area()
.interpolate("monotone")
.x(function(d) { return x(format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0])); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d3.values(d)[0]); });

var area2 = d3.svg.area()
.interpolate("monotone")
.x(function(d) { return x2(format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0])); })
.y0(height2)
.y1(function(d) { return y2(d3.values(d)[0]); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
.attr("id", "clip")
.append("rect")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0]); })));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d3.values(d)[0]; }))]);
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());

focus.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .attr("d", area);

focus.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

focus.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

context.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("d", area2);

context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
  .call(xAxis2);

context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x brush")
  .call(brush)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .attr("y", -6)
  .attr("height", height2 + 7);

focus.append("g").selectAll('dot')
.data(data)
.enter().append("svg:circle")
.attr("cx",function(d){ return x(format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0]));})
.attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d3.values(d)[0]);})
.attr("r", function(d){ return 4;})
.on('mouseover', function(d){ d3.select(this).attr('r', 8)})
.on('mouseout', function(d){ d3.select(this).attr('r', 4)});    

function brush() {
x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
focus.select("path").attr("d", area);
focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
focus.select("circle").attr("cx",function(d){ return x(format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0]));}).attr("cy", function(d){    return y(d3.values(d)[0]);});
}
```

I have created a Fiddle for this here: http://jsfiddle.net/PyvZ7/.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/PyvZ7/7/

Don't forget to apply `clip-path` to the group. Your code used `select` instead of `selectAll`. So the transforms were not applying to all the circles within the group. Also `selectAll` is a css3 selector. You need to make sure you do `selectAll('.dot')` instead of `selectAll('dot')` as the latter would mean a tag and the former would mean elements having a class `dot`.

Here is the modified code:

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var data = [{
    'Wed Jan 23 00:00:00 IST 2013': 3383387
}, {
    'Thu Jan 24 00:00:00 IST 2013': 3883387
}, {
    'Fri Jan 25 00:00:00 IST 2013': 4383387
}, {
    'Sat Jan 26 00:00:00 IST 2013': 2383387
}, {
    'Sun Jan 27 00:00:00 IST 2013': 5383387
}, {
    'Mon Jan 28 00:00:00 IST 2013': 2283387
}];

var format = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S IST %Y");

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brush);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0])); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d3.values(d)[0]); });

var area2 = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x2(format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0])); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d3.values(d)[0]); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

  x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0]); })));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d3.values(d)[0]; }))]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .attr("d", area);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("d", area2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);

    var circlegroup = focus.append("g");
    circlegroup.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
    circlegroup.selectAll('.dot')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'dot')
    .attr("cx",function(d){ return x(format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0]));})
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d3.values(d)[0]);})
    .attr("r", function(d){ return 4;})
    .on('mouseover', function(d){ d3.select(this).attr('r', 8)})
    .on('mouseout', function(d){ d3.select(this).attr('r', 4)});    

function brush() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select("path").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  circlegroup.selectAll(".dot").attr("cx",function(d){ return x(format.parse(d3.keys(d)[0]));}).attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d3.values(d)[0]);});
}
```